# Convert eclipse java project to maven module project

Tags: java, maven, m2eclipse

I have java project, i want to convert a multi-module project (module). I have a parent project, i want to add my existing project in parent. I like a eclipse style file structure does it possible to add existing project in Parent.

Thank you,

Regards and Metta,
Ichiro hang

Answer (score 8):

First create pom.xml files in all projects, then:

Old school:

Run `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, switch to eclipse and do `Import > Existing Projects`

New School:

Install m2e, don't run eclipse:eclipse (because it has no effect on m2e) and do `Import > Maven > Existing Maven Projects`

Don't mix the two, they are not compatible with each other.

Comment: Hi Sean, Okay let's say i have project "D" which is pure eclipse java project. I right-click > enable dependency management > it create POM.xml file. My problem is, I want make project "D" as child project of parent project "A". Project "A" contain packaging type "POM". I attempt another way also, after i turn my existing project "D" into mavan java project. I delete project (not physical location) and then, i Import > Maven > Existing Maven Project. However it does not make linked. Any suggestion

Answer (score 2):

You have to configure the pom.xml of the child project ("D").
You need to insert the  tag with the follow configuration:
groupId, artifactId and version.

And into the parent's pom.xml you need to add the new module child ( tag).

e.g.
D pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.project.A</groupId>
    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>
```

A pom.xml

```
<modules>
    <module>D</module> --> It is the artifact Id
    <module>...</module>
    <module>...</module>
</modules>
```

Answer (score 0):

Install [Maven Plugin for Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) (m2e). Then in your project (command line), at the root level type `mvn eclipse:eclipse`. Reimport the generated project in Eclipse (Import Existing Projects into Workspace) and you should be all set.

Comment: That's nonsense. Use either m2e, or eclipse:eclipse, but not both.

Comment: I have m2eclipse. I have a project of multi-module, what i want is to convert my existing eclipse project to multi-module for e.g a project "A" is parent project which contain "POM" type packaging and there are child projects "B" and "C", which has linked to project "A". Now I have existing eclipse project called "D", which want to linked with parent project "A". How to solve this issue ? I am not looking create new multi-module project. Thank you